# Syntax error in parameter formula of field calculator funtion

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator

I'm using a QGIS 2.8.1 in windows.
Have some doubts with syntax when use string in python console. I want to use the field calculator funtion like:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', input, field_name, type_field, width, precision, Create new field, formula, output)
```

In the formula parameter I want use the condition:

```
case when "Municipio" is NULL then 'PENICHE'
```

I know that `PENICHE` is a string, so have to be between '' (plicas) but all the expression should be too between '' (plicas) like:

```
' case when "Municipio" is NULL then 'PENICHE' '
```

The problem is that there happened a syntax error.

How can I correct the expression?

---

The code I´m using is:

processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', input, "Mun", 2, 27, 0, True, ' case when "Municipio" is NULL then 'PENICHE' else "Municipio" end ', output)

---

I used formula = "case when \"Municipio\" is NULL then 'PENICHE' end" know its working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Joseph is correct about the syntax of the `CASE` statement, your Python issue stems from string quoting.

You can use either `'` or `"` to quote strings, and you don't have to escape the other character if used, but you do have to escape the same character. Or you can triple quote (ie `'''`) which will also allow multi line quotes.

In other words:

```py
# this should work 
formula = "case when \"Municipio\" is NULL then 'PENICHE' end" 
# so should this
formula = 'case when "Municipio" is NULL then \'PENICHE\' end'

# or you can use multi line quotes
formula = '''
case when "Municipio" is NULL then 'PENICHE' end
'''
```

Comment: +1, that's a much easier method than typing the formula inside the function!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `end` to close of your **case** statement. The following should work:

```
case when "Municipio" is NULL then 'PENICHE' end
```

---

**Tip:**

What I normally do is to make an expression in the field calculator from the **GUI** before adding it to the python console. This way, it tells you immediately if your formula will work or not instead of running it though the python console and receiving an error which you then have to try and figure out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I use your suggestion and didn't work, I try these two ways: ' case when "Municipio" is NULL then 'PENICHE' end ' and case when "Municipio" is NULL then 'PENICHE' end     any help?

Comment: appeared in the two ways a syntax error!

Comment: Are you receiving an error or does it run and nothing happens? Is the `Municipio` field a string field? Could you edit your question to include **exactly** the code you are using please?

Comment: I'm receiving a syntax error that don't let run the code , the Municipio field is a string field. The code I'm using is: processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', input, "Mun", 2, 27, 0, True, ' case when "Municipio" is NULL then 'PENICHE' else "Municipio" end ', output)