# Field calculator using pyqgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, field-calculator, python-2.7

I have some fields calculations and I want to create a pyqgis plugin using my expressions but I get Unexpected errors. For example if I do my task using field calculator in QGIS then it works, if i use the same expression in QGIS modeler it works again but does not work when using the same expression in pyqgis.
I dont know why because I use the same expression.

Here is the pyqgis code :

```
outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_6=processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_5['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'mynewfield',1,10.0,0.0,True,'left( "field1", strpos( "field1" ,'_')-1)',None)
```

and I get syntax error.

that is from model export and in the model working nice.

Finally i try advanced python field calculator but that now work for me.

If I use `value=left( "field1", strpos( "field1" ,'_')-1)` then I get error `no module left`. If i use `value='left( "field1", strpos( "field1" ,'_')-1)'` then I get this error -
[image: error]

Comment: It's very likely that it's having an issue with how you are quoting strings within the expression. Check out the answer to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160698/syntax-error-in-parameter-formula-of-field-calculator-funtion. So, I would expect something like `value='left( "field1", strpos( "field1" ,\'_\')-1)'` to perhaps work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your PyQGIS code when you are writing the expression -

```
'left( "field1", strpos( "field1" ,'_')-1)'
```

use escape characters for defining quotes inside like -

```
'left( \"field1\", strpos( \"field1\" ,\'_\')-1)'
```

I've tried it on QGIS 2.18 and it should work for you.

As as far as the Advanced Python Field Calculator goes, it works quite different from the default QGIS Field Calculator. You may refer this [blogpost](https://anitagraser.com/2013/04/20/advanced-python-field-calculator/) for more information about its use.

Comment: Is it necessary to escape the `"` characters, or would it suffice to only escape the `'` characters since they're the ones used to contain the expression?

Comment: It would suffice to just escape `'` in this case. However if the expression would have been enclosed in `"` then the opposite would be true. In my experience it is better to escape all the quotes as the expression may be written in any manner.

Comment: Another effective way would be to use triple quote `'''` which would remove any necessity for escape characters. Thank you @JohnR for the link in your comment where I found this information.

Comment: @nash thank you i follow proposal by nash and problem sovled thank you again good job